# Is csvsimple compatible with multicolumn in rows other than the header?

Tags: multicolumn, csvsimple

I want to shorten a tabular by making text in the first column consume more than one cell in the last (rather than first) rows of the tabular. I know `csvsimple` accepts macros however lines can't be started by a slash `\`, so I added a dot `.` to the beginning of the last line with the `\multicolumn` command.

However, that does not work. How could I accomplish this? Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
a,b,c
d,e,f
g,h,i
.\multicolumn{2}{c}{j},,k
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\csvreader[
tabular = ccc,
late after line = \\,
head to column names,
no check column count,
respect none]
{data.csv}
{}
{\a & \b & \c}

\end{document}
```

Comment: once you start needing to put tex commands in the csv file isn't it simpler just to make the file a `tabular` and `\input` it rather than use a package to parse it? Basically you just need to use `&` instead of `,` and put `\\ ` at the end of every line.

Comment: you're right, that's certainly much simpler. I'm teaching a friend LaTeX and he got quite fascinated by the fact you can just import CSV files, so I wanted to see if he could keep working that way.